# How to replace Jersey by Resteasy on a Jetty server?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jax-rs, resteasy

I build a Java REST application that I want to deploy on a Jetty server.

I try to work with last versions of libraries (Java 8, Servlet 3.1, Jetty 9.4.7 and Resteasy 3.1.4).

I already make my server work with Jersey 2.26 but it has a limitation I hear that Resteasy does not have:

With Jersey I can't deploy if I define an interface with `@Path` annotation defined on the class because when I implement the interface the deployment failed due to a conflict about this non-unique resource. In other word to make it work I need to move the following commented annotation into the implementation :

```
//@Path("li")
public interface ILaptopInfo {

    @Path("test/{test}")
    @GET
    public String test(@PathParam("test") String who);
}
```

I use Maven so I removed Jersey's dependencies and add Resteasy one's as [documentation says](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#standalone_resteasy):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I does not change my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false"
    version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

But when I start my server I got a resteasy WARN and then a `No class in holder javax.ws.rs.core.Application` stacktrace. It makes me think it does not scan properly my project to find my resource or Resteasy stack does not properly start the scanning. Do you have an idea about that I could miss?

Below the stacktrace I got:

```
2017-10-26 14:12:33.519:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.7.v20170914
2017-10-26 14:12:34.416:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=628ms
2017-10-26 14:12:34.432:WARN:oeja.WebServletAnnotation:main: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher defines neither @WebServlet.value nor @WebServlet.urlPatterns
2017-10-26 14:12:34.770:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2017-10-26 14:12:34.770:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2017-10-26 14:12:34.770:INFO:oejs.session:main: Scavenging every 660000ms
2017-10-26 14:12:34.933:WARN:oejshC.ROOT:main: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: No class in holder javax.ws.rs.core.Application@83f91b4==null,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2017-10-26 14:12:34.971:WARN:oejshC.ROOT:main: unavailable
```

Comment: Do you have a class that extends [javax.ws.rs.core.Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) and is annotated with `@ApplicationPath("...")?

Answer (score 0):

I had your same issue. Try this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.Application</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```